# What is the $\{q_i\}$-$t$ space called?

Tags: classical-mechanics, time, terminology, coordinate-systems

In classical mechanics, the [configuration space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space_(physics)) of a system of $f$ degrees of freedom is the $f$-dimensional space of the set of generalized coordinates $\{q_i\}=(q_1,q_2...q_f)$ of a system. While talking about the principle of extremum action, one draws a path in the $\{q_i\}$-$t$ "plane" where $t$ represents time. Does this space which contains both the set of generalized coordinate and time has any name?

Comment: If you think of the coordinates as functions $q_i(t)$, then your space is the domain of these functions. Since it is a trivial manifold/fiber bundle without relativity theory, it is probably not special enough to have a specific name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name could vary from author to author. In a non-technical setting I think you would find it under the name "extended configuration space". In more specialized contexts (e.g. Hamiltonian mechanics on symplectic spaces, field theory on fiber bundles, etc.) they are called contact manifolds or even just configuration spaces.